# Maximum number of regions in a disk partitioned by pairs of parallel chords

Tags: co.combinatorics, gt.geometric-topology, mg.metric-geometry, discrete-geometry, combinatorial-optimization

We are given a disk $D$ in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let $C$ be its boundary (i.e., the circle bounding $D$ on its plane). Let $P(n,d)$ be a set of $n$ pairs of chords of $C$ such that for each $\{c,c'\}\in P(n,d)$, $c$ and $c'$ are parallel and the distance between them is equal to $0<d<r$, where $r$ is the length of the radius of $C$.

Finally, let $R$ be the set of all connected regions of $D$ obtained by cutting $D$ by all pairs of chords of $P(n,d)$, in such a way that each region of $A\in R$

- does not contain any point belonging to any of such chords,
- is bounded by some of these chords or $C$, and
- there exists a pair of chords $\{c,c'\}\in P(n,d)$ such that all points of $A$ are located between $c$ and $c'$.

---

**Question**: What is the maximum number $m(n,d)$ of regions in $R$ over all possible set of $P(n,d)$?

---

[image: Case n=3]
***Example:*** *For all $d$, we have $m(1,d)=1$, $m(2,d)=5$, $m(3,d)=13$ - In fact, I actually conjecture that $m$ depends on $n$ solely.*

Comment: This may be just $A058331-2n$ (http://oeis.org/A058331) or $2n^2-2n+1$, if cutting regions by parallel lines is the same as cutting regions by hyperbolas, and there are always $2n$ regions to remove as being outside all the lines.

Comment: Very interesting! Thank you @MattF. Maybe there is an easy way to prove that it is just quadratic in $n$ (it would be sufficient for my purpose I guess, even if I am working on hyperspheres in high dimensions in the original problem I trying to solve).

Comment: The maximum number of cells in an arrangement of $n$ lines is $n(n+1)/2+1$. So your $2n$ lines could make at most $2n^2+n+1$ cells, if all were in $D$. So indeed there is a quadratic upper bound. MattF was seeking an exact formula.

Comment: @MattF.: Nice conjecture! Could you explain the intuition behind: hyperbolas = parallel lines?

Comment: Well, topologically the hyperbolas are the same as pairs of parallel lines, and the configuration of the plane most cut up by two hyperbolas is topologically the same as the configuration most cut up by two pairs of parallel lines.

Comment: @Matt F. But any pair of arbitrary disjoint simple open curves is also topologically the same, yes the number of pieces obtained out of two such pairs may be even infinite.

Comment: The problem  with hyperbolas in A058331 is solved, say, looking the configuration from a long distance, i.e., replacing each hyperbole with a pair of incident lines, and recalling they are hyperboles, so adding the n-th hyperbole makes  4n-2 new pieces, one less than a pair of incident lines. This gives the upper bound of $2n^2+1$, which is realized by any generic choice.

Comment: (Yet I do not see clearly how this can be exactly related with the OP's problem, because it is not clear what is the number of new pieces  of type $R$ made by a new pair of parallel lines)

Comment: @PenelopeBenenati How do you realize the number $m(3)=15$? I can see $12=3^2+3$ pieces of type R, and in general, $n^2+n$ .

Comment: @PietroMajer I wrote that for $n=3$ we get $m=13$. I just added a pictorial explanation. I am basically interested in proving that $m$ is quadratic in $n$, which now seems obvious to me.

Comment: FYI, the site doesn't support MathJax in image descriptions: cf. https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/327908/295232

Comment: Thank you @Glorfindel, I did not know it.

Comment: Thank you, I see I misunderstood the last condition -- c and c' need not to meet $\partial A$

Comment: Thanks to you @PietroMajer, it has been an opportunity to clarify with a picture.